# What type of injuries did Kylo Ren receive in the lightsaber battle at the end of The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

During the lightsaber battle at the end of *The Force Awakens*, what type of injuries did Kylo Ren receive?  At one point it appears as if his left foot had been amputated at the ankle, and after that he has trouble walking, but later it appears that his foot is still attached.

Comment: Wait, how do you get an ankle amputated? That'd be a neat, although painful trick.

Comment: I assume s/he meant "foot amputated at the ankle" or something.

Comment: Ha :).  It is like getting your neck chopped off.  A lot of other stuff goes with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kylo suffers a number of relatively minor injuries during his fights with Finn and Rey

- **A grazing cut to his upper right arm**

[image]

> ***His blade tip sheared Ren’s arm. It didn’t do much more than sizzle
> his opponent’s skin.** But Ren backpedaled, reassessing Finn.* - <sub><sup>[The Force Awakens: Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

- **A shallow stab to the left pectoral region (his upper chest)**

[image]

- **A kick to his stomach (and a painful fall onto his posterior)**

[image]

- **A shallow cut to his forehead and right cheek extending down to his neck**

[image]

> *Taking **a glancing blow to the head and chest**, he went down, **a
> prominent burn slashed across his face**. Weakened, he reached out
> toward his lightsaber, trying to draw it to him.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Force Awakens: Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))</sup></sub>

For the record, what appears to be a leg-cut was in fact Rey cutting off the edge of Ren's cloak. Although he seems to have slipped in the snow, it doesn't look like Rey hit him.

[image]
<sub><sup>Clip from DVD Extra; "**Blueprint of a Battle - The Snow Fight**"</sup></sub>

Comment: Edit for info from adult novel, but I saw @Richard already added that info.

Comment: Where is the last gif from? The last shot shows a bluescreen behind them and the lightsabers have no white center like they should!

Comment: Odd. The Skywalker line usually has a prediliction for losing a hand.

Comment: @RedCaio - It's from the "making of" featurette